# Systemd service taking a long time to run

Tags: python-3.x, linux, systemd

I am having service running as background service in EC2 instance. but it taking a long time to start a new one or restart a service ( refer to image: I reboot EC2, and a service restart at 9:00, but at the 11:32, a service print the first log ).
[image]

Here is my service config file in etc/systemd/system:

```
[Unit]
Description=file scanner ...
After=network.target


[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/apps/file-scanner
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 main.py
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/file-scanner/logs.log
StandardError=file:/var/log/file-scanner/logs.log


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Please help.

Comment: What does your main.py contain ?  You can see the systemd log of startup immediately, but your app is taking time to make its first log ?

Comment: My main.py basically is have white loop every 10 seconds, and print message. It takes 1 hours to started and print the first message. I only faced this issue recently.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting to start your python script from command line to test how long it takes:

```
  /usr/bin/python3 /apps/file-scanner/main.py
```

If it takes as long than you need to fix your `/apps/file-scanner/main.py` and profile it to learn what takes long time. Use standard python3 profiling tools and put many logging message.

It is very possible your `/apps/file-scanner/main.py` script is consuming most of the memory resources and cpu resources therefore your script takes very long to start.

Also learn to use [`top` command](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-top-command/) to monitor machine utilization at runtime.